# Socket.io Detect whether reconnecting or completely disconnecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a chat application with Node.js and Socket.io, and on disconnect, the remaining user receives an alert saying that their partner disconnected.

The problem is that every once in a while, Socket.io automatically disconnects then reconnects. My chat application is triggering the alert, even though the partner hasn't really disconnected.

Code:

```
var clients = {};
var soloClients = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    //Session start
    socket.on('sessionStart', function () {
        clients[socket.id] = socket;
        soloClients.push(socket.id);

        var searchClients = function(){
            if(soloClients.length > 1){
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * soloClients.length);
                if(soloClients[rand] && soloClients[rand] != socket.id){
                    if(clients[soloClients[rand]]){
                        var you = clients[socket.id];
                        var partner = clients[soloClients[rand]]

                        clients[partner.id]['partner'] = you.id;
                        clients[you.id]['partner'] = partner.id;
                        soloClients.splice(soloClients.indexOf(you.id), 1);
                        soloClients.splice(soloClients.indexOf(partner.id), 1);

                        partner.emit('partnerConnect', null);
                        socket.emit('partnerConnect', null);
                    }
                    else{
                        soloClients.splice(rand, 1);
                        searchClients;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    searchClients();
                }
            }
        };
        searchClients();
    });

    //On disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        soloClients.splice(soloClients.indexOf(socket.id), 1);

        if(clients[socket.id]){
            if(clients[clients[socket.id]['partner']]){
                clients[clients[socket.id]['partner']].emit('partnerDisconnect', null);
            }
            delete clients[socket.id];
        }
    });
});
```

I was wondering if there is any way to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this behavior isn't supposed to happen, it was just a bug in that version. This bug has been fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to find out the real reason why the client gets disconnected? I.e. is it a bad connection, or firewall issues, or something else?

Also, you should check the error you get from the disconnect, if it's a clean disconnect (no error) you do the normal notification, but if it's an error you maybe want to handle it differently.